# Only add even numbers to Array using JavaScript Proxy

Tags: javascript, javascript-proxy

I'm learning JavaScript Proxy .

By using **set trap** i only want to add even number to Array. But every time throw

> Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property
> 'length'

Here is my code example.

```js
//Only even numbers will be added here. We are using Js Proxy

let evenNumbers = [];

evenNumbers = new Proxy(evenNumbers, {
    set(target, p, value, receiver) {
        if ( (value % 2) === 0 ) {
            target[p] = value;
            return true
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }
});

evenNumbers.push(2);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You neet to return `true` for both cases, because

> **[Return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set#return_value)**
>
> The `set()` method should return a boolean value.
>
> - Return `true` to indicate that assignment succeeded.
> - If the `set()` method returns `false`, and the assignment happened in strict-mode code, a [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) will be thrown.

`push` calls the proxy twice, one by pushing the value and another times to change the `length` property. To avoid unnecessary more action whithin in this proxy, you could exit early with this unwanted property.

```js
let evenNumbers = [];

evenNumbers = new Proxy(evenNumbers, {
    set (target, p, value, receiver) {
        if (p === 'length') return true; // exclude this property
        if (value % 2 === 0) {
            target[p] = value;
        }
        return true;
    }
});

evenNumbers.push(2);
console.log(evenNumbers.length); // 1
evenNumbers.push(3);
console.log(evenNumbers.length); // Still 1
console.log(evenNumbers);        // [ 2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the function `.push()` tries to update the length (`evenNumbers.length = 1`), and that's not being allowed by the trap.

Try this:

```js
let evenNumbers = [];

evenNumbers = new Proxy(evenNumbers, {
    set(target, p, value, receiver) {
        if ( isFinite(p) ) {
            // The key is a number (index), so there's code trying to add/change an element of the array.
            if ( (value % 2) === 0 ) {
                target[p] = value;
                return true
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
});

evenNumbers.push(2); // OK
evenNumbers.push(3); // TypeError
```

Comment: Thanks @D. Pardal, But are there any way to skip the length or others property that automatically assigned by javascript ?

Comment: @sahedmoral That's what my answer does.